# Dynamically include a module in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my app, I have a Model which should include a module. The model has an attribute called 'format', which determines which module should be included. For instance, if `format == 0`, then the Model should `include SingleElimination`, whereas if `format == 1`, then the Model should `include DoubleElmination`. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def include_format
  case format
  when 1
    extend SingleElimination
  when 2
    extend DoubleElmination
  end
end

after_initialize :include_format
```

Comment: I have a question: Why is extend used over include?

Comment: @Max I use `extend` because `include` is not defined in context of a method body. So the accepted answer will raise a `MethodNotDefined`. Furthermore `include` as is descriped in that answer works that way when called in a class body. That is however a different context then in a method body where `extend` adds it where it should go.

Comment: I see, thank you for that insight. I was not aware of that distinction when extending. Your implementation is not correct, however. You cannot call format in an after_initialize filter. I get a too few arguments error. To correct this, I had to use a lambda. I edited with what worked for me.